# What does "dd:0<1" mean?

Tags: shell-script, dd, android

I am running a shell script on a Android phone, filling the space up by create some files. Part of it as follows:

```bsh
while ((i < count)); do
    dd if=/dev/zero bs=$file_size count=1 of=file.$i.bin
    ((i++))
done
sync
```

However, it prints `dd: 0<1` in the shell. I could not find similar questions on the internet.

Any hint？Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$file_size` when this happens?

Comment: As an input parameter,which I set 1:                                    file_size_MB=$1
file_size=$((file_size_MB*1024*1024))

Comment: So what is `$1` then? You know, like 0 multiplied by anything is still 0.

Answer (score 3):

[just to create a search result on the internet]

`dd: 0<1` means that you give a value of 0 to a `dd` argument which expects something greater than or equal to 1. In your case, you have called `dd` with `bs=0` which is not acceptable.

Most `dd` implementations have a friendlier error message for it, just as  android's/toybox's `dd` used to in the past.

That particular error message is produced by the [`atolx_range()`](https://github.com/landley/toybox/blob/ef30ea278b5cee37782008ff9369720acd1a7337/lib/lib.c#L328) as called by the [toybox](http://landley.net/toybox/) implementation of of [`dd`](https://github.com/landley/toybox/blob/ef30ea278b5cee37782008ff9369720acd1a7337/toys/pending/dd.c#L151).